# Prove that $0<\frac{\ln(\frac{1}{\ln2})}{\ln2}<1$

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms

How can I prove this statement?

$$0<\frac{\ln(\frac{1}{\ln2})}{\ln2}<1$$

I have tried using the fact that $1=\frac{1}{\ln e}<\frac{1}{\ln 2}$.

I have also tried writing it as $\log_2(\frac{1}{\ln2})$, but with no luck.

I need to prove that to show that a certain function is negative.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Use natural log is increasing function so your inequality is basically equivalent to $ e<2^2=4$

Comment: Can you see that the fraction is positive? For the other direction, write it as $\ln(\frac{1}{\ln2}) < \ln 2$ and apply the exponential function.

Comment: Use $\log(x)<x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$e<2^2<e^2$$
$$\implies 1<2\ln(2)<2$$
$$\implies \frac 12<\ln(2)<1$$

$$\implies 1<\frac{1}{\ln(2)}<2$$

$$\implies 0<\ln(\frac{1}{\ln(2)})<\ln(2)$$
$$\implies 0<\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\right)}{\ln(2)}<1$$

Comment: Very nice answer :-).....+1.

Comment: @Sebastiano Hi Sebastiano and inter Milano.

Comment: Hi..........19 th "scudetto" :-))))

Comment: @Sebastiano I hope everything goes well with you friend of Squadra Azzura.

Comment: +1 I think that this is the better answer, very clean and neat.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The statement is equivalent to showing that $$\ln 2>\frac{1}{2}\iff2\ln 2>1\iff\ln4>1.$$
Since this is clearly true, since $2<e<3$, we now know that $$\ln 2>\frac{1}{2}.$$
This means that $$\frac{1}{\ln 2}<2$$ and therefore
$$\ln\left(\frac{1}{\ln 2}\right)<\ln 2$$
and therefore
$$\frac{\ln \frac{1}{\ln 2}}{\ln 2}<1.$$
The fact that the expression is positive is quite obvious, since it is equal to $2$ positive quantities divided by one another, which is always positive.

---

I hope that helps. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Very nice also this answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you for your kind words :)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @CalculusLover My pleasure!

Answer (score 2):

During the proof, we will use the fact that: $$ x<y \iff \ln x<\ln y $$

> Blockquote

Let's prove that the fraction is positive:
$$  2<e \iff \ln 2 < \ln e = 1 \iff \frac{1}{\ln 2} > 1 \iff \\ \iff \ln \left(\frac{1}{\ln 2} \right) > \ln 1 =0 \ \ \textrm{Numerator is positive.}  $$
$$   2>1 \iff \ln 2 > \ln 1 = 0 \ \ \textrm{Denominator is positive. }$$

Both the numerator and denominator are positive. Then the fraction must be positive.
Let's prove that the fraction is smaller than 1:
$$e < 4 \iff \sqrt e < 2 \iff \ln e^{1/2} < \ln 2 \iff \frac{1}{2}< \ln 2 \iff \frac{1}{\ln 2} < 2 \iff \\ \iff \ln\left( \frac{1}{\ln 2}\right) < \ln 2  \iff \frac{\ln\left( \frac{1}{\ln 2}\right)}{\ln 2 } < 1$$
Then $ 0<\frac{\ln\left( \frac{1}{\ln 2}\right)}{\ln 2 }<1  $.  $\\ \blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you for the answer!